# How to send log message from userdata execution to AWS EC2 console for Windows AMI?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, user-data, ec2-ami

I want to send some message logs like Step-1 done , next Step-2 done from the powershell script block  to the aws ec2 console screen for windows 2016 instance.

Can any body know how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output), the console for an EC2 instance:

> For Windows instances, the instance console output includes the last three system event log errors.

So you can use the PowerShell `Write-EventLog` [scriptlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) to write an error event to the System log.

Example:

```
Write-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "MyApp" -EntryType Error -Message "Step-1 done"
```